# How to enable syntax check when developing Flutter native code in vscode?

Tags: java, android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode to develop Flutter android application, and I need to use Java to do native development. However the vscode is not showing any syntax prompt or errors for Java. Any settings I need to setup for vscode?

Comment: Java Linting, Intellisense, formatting, refactoring and so on is provided by the extension Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat, Check if you've disable it.

Comment: The `Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat` extension is enabled.

Comment: Gradle-based Android projects are not supported. Please refer to https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java